# Why am I getting an indentation error, "unexpected indent" in my code? Python

Tags: python, indentation

On the first line of my code, I seem to be getting an indentation error. I have 2 spaces as an indent on my code, as I always do since my class requires it, but for the first time I'm getting an error for it.

My code looks like this at the start.

```
  import math

  def main():
```

Comment: You indented where you were not supposed to.

Comment: Please post the whole code. [Copy and paste](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut,_copy,_and_paste) it in the edit field, select the whole code, and press `Ctrl`+`K`.

Comment: check spaces/tabs. read about what python requires in the way of spaces/tabs

Comment: My class doesnt allow us to post our code online, I'm only getting the error at the very beginning though.

Comment: @user3458006 Must be a high value asset class then. Directly from the class room to the production server.

Answer (score 2):

You should not indent Python code unless you have something like `def`, `for`, `if` and similar such things preceding the indentation block.

For example:

```
for thing in variable:
  #indent code
  pass

def aFunction():
  #indent
  pass

#invalid indentation:
 def aFunction2():
  pass
```

As you can imagine, the code not only becomes hard for human eyes to interpret, but also for your machine to interpret, because it cannot realise where the indentation starts or ends.

Speak to your teacher about this, they might be using an interpreter which allows them to indent their entire script by a particular amount. I would never recommend this though.

Comment: This was exactly right, i needed to not indent before my definition, thank you!

Comment: No problem :) Come say hi in the Python chat sometime.